# How do I use mongodb to count only collections that match two fields

Tags: mongodb

I have some documents that have a `newOne`: `true` or `false` and that have an owner tag on them. I want to count all fields that have both `newOne : true` and the owner field equal to "MSlaton" How do I go about this in mongodb?

Thank you!

Comment: [`db.collection.count( { "newOne": true, "owner": "MSlaton" } )`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) or `db.collection.find( { "newOne": true, "owner": "MSlaton" } ).count()`

Comment: @chridam please post this as an answer.

Comment: @Philipp I think there is a possible dupe lying around, not too sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **[`count()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)** method as

```
db.collection.count( { "newOne": true, "owner": "MSlaton" } )
```

which is equivalent to

```
db.collection.find( { "newOne": true, "owner": "MSlaton" } ).count()
```

Another route, albeit slower, would be via the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** where you run the following aggregation operation to get the count:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "newOne": true, "owner": "MSlaton" } },
    { "$group": { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": 1 } } }
]);
```

The aggregation operation is slower since it reads each and every document in the collection and processes it which can only be halfway in the same order of magnitude with **[`count()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)** when doing it over only a significantly large collection.